# How can I print the difference of each value from the highest value?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to print the differences of each value from the highest value but I dont know what to do. Here is my example

```
    from array import *

    arr = array('i',[])

    array_length = (5)

    for i in range(array_length):
        element = int(input('Enter a number: ')
        arr.append(element)
    print('\nArray List:',arr)

    def largest(arr, array_length):
        max = arr[0]
        for i in range(array_length):
            if arr[i] > max:
                max = arr[i]
        return max
    answer = largest(arr, array_length)
    print('\nThe highest value is:',answer)
```

Comment: I would want to critique your code a little bit.

Comment: First, the 'largest' function can be replaced with the built-in function 'max.' However, if you want to make the function yourself, that is okay. Second, the max variable is not supposed to be used since again, it is the name of a built-in function in python. Third, why do you need to import the array function if it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getAllArrayDifferenceFromMax(arr):
    biggest = max(arr)
    return [biggest-x for x in arr]
```

So basically I first got the largest number in the array, then returned an array that gets the xth item in the array and then do: `biggest-arr[x]` that's all.

I know it may seem a bit unclear, so comment down your questions.